# My SongOrganizer Script displays else echo when it shouldn't. Line 67. How do I fix it?

Tags: php

In my script on line 67 the echo statement "Your Song has been added to the list" displays before I add any songs to the list. Can anyone tell me why? It is under the comment step 8 and step 9. I have xdebug set up with sublime text 3 but I have no clue on how to use it. When I set breakpoints and run the script I get a bunch of uninitialized variables in my Context pane.

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<head>
<title>Song Organizer</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Song Organizer</h1>
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
        if ((file_exists("SongOrganizer/songs.txt")) && (filesize("SongOrganizer/songs.txt") != 0)) {
            $SongArray = file("SongOrganizer/songs.txt");
            switch ($_GET['action']) {
                case 'Remove Duplicates':
                    $SongArray = array_unique($SongArray);
                    $SongArray = array_values($SongArray);
                    break;
                case 'Sort Ascending':
                    sort($SongArray);
                    break;
                case 'Shuffle':
                    shuffle($SongArray);
                    break;

            } // End of the Switch Statement


            if (count($SongArray)>0) {
                $NewSongs = implode($SongArray);
                $SongStore = fopen("SongOrganizer/songs.txt", "wb");
                if ($SongStore === false)
                    echo "There was an error updating the song file\n";
             else {
                fwrite($SongStore, $NewSongs);
                fclose($SongStore);
                }
            }
            else
                unlink("SongOrganizer/songs.txt");
        }
    }


    // Step 7
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $SongToAdd = stripslashes($_POST['SongName']) . "\n";
        $ExistingSongs = array();
        if (file_exists("SongOrganizer/songs.txt") && filesize("SongOrganizer/songs.txt") > 0) {
            $ExistingSongs = file("SongOrganizer/songs.txt");

        }
    }   

            // Step 8 and Step 9    
            if (in_array($SongToAdd, $ExistingSongs)) {
                echo "<p>The song you entered already exists!<br />\n";
                echo "Your song was not added to the list.</p>";
            } else {
                $SongFile = fopen("SongOrganizer/songs.txt", "ab");
                if ($SongFile === false)
                    echo "There was an error saving your message!\n";
                else {
                    fwrite($SongFile, $SongToAdd);
                    fclose($SongFile);
                    echo "Your Song has been added to the list.\n";
                }
            }

    // Step 10
    if ((!file_exists("SongOrganizer/songs.txt")) || (filesize("SongOrganizer/songs.txt") == 0))
        echo "<p>There are no songs in the list.</p>\n";
    else {
        $SongArray = file("SongOrganizer/songs.txt");
        echo "<table border=\"1\" width=\"100%\" style=\"background-color:lightgray\">\n";
        foreach ($SongArray as $Song) {
            echo "<tr>\n";
            echo "<td>" . htmlentities($Song) . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
        echo "</table>\n";
    }
?>

<p>
<a href="SongOrganizer.php?action=Sort%20Ascending">Sort Song List</a><br />
<a href="SongOrganizer.php?action=Remove%20Duplicates">Remove Duplicate Songs</a><br />
<a href="SongOrganizer.php?action=Shuffle">Randomize Song List</a><br />
</p>

<form action="SongOrganizer.php" method="post">
<p>Add a New Song</p>
<p>Song Name: <input type="text" name="SongName" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Song to List" /><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset Song Name" /></p>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I added these lines in the beginning to find errors:      error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: I also added an echo 'File found, continue execution'; - Right after first nested if statement

Comment: I still can't find the problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer my problem was that step 8 and step 9 should have been a nested if statement inside of step 7. like so:

```
// Step 7
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $SongToAdd = stripslashes($_POST['SongName']) . "\n";
    $ExistingSongs = array();
    if (file_exists("SongOrganizer/songs.txt") && filesize("SongOrganizer/songs.txt") > 0) {
        $ExistingSongs = file("SongOrganizer/songs.txt");


        // Step 8 and Step 9    
        if (in_array($SongToAdd, $ExistingSongs)) {
            echo "<p>The song you entered already exists!<br />\n";
            echo "Your song was not added to the list.</p>";
        } else {
            $SongFile = fopen("SongOrganizer/songs.txt", "ab");
            if ($SongFile === false)
                echo "There was an error saving your message!\n";
            else {
                fwrite($SongFile, $SongToAdd);
                fclose($SongFile);
                echo "Your Song has been added to the list.\n";
            }
        }

    }
}
```